# Transfer Enqueued Call to Conference Using Twilio

Tags: twilio

Imagine there is an incoming call currently [enqueued](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/enqueue) via Twilio.

I want to transfer this call a new [conference line](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/api/conference).

Currently, my app "updates" the call with a redirect URL that responds with the following TwiML.

**Unfortunately, it just hangs there, listening to music, and I never enter the conference.**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
    <Dial>
        <Conference endConferenceOnExit="true" startConferenceOnEnter="true" waitUrl="http://example.com/music">
            {{CallSid}}
        </Conference>
    </Dial>
</Response>
```

Note that the `{{CallSid}}` is dynamically updated with the call identifier (aka [Call SID](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223180488-What-is-a-Call-SID-)). Also, I have not tried this with a second phone (*because maybe it won't connect to the conference line until there is more than one person?*)

Comment: Well, adding two people to call did not work... Both are stuck on hold music for conference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

First up, your question in parentheses was indeed correct, a conference will not start with one person in, so will just play the hold music until someone else joins.

Secondly, once you added a second call you were still hearing hold music. However, for the `<Conference>` identifier, you said you were using the `CallSid`. That identifier is unique per call leg, so each of your calls would have different `CallSid`s and thus would join different conference calls. To first ensure that this is the issue, I would test your code with a static identifier for the conference (`<Conference>Test</Conference>` for example). If you can get callers talking together like that, then you will need to find a way to identify a conference independent of the individual `CallSid`s and use that as the identifier so that you can join the calls together.

Let me know if that helps at all.

Comment: You’re right. Not sure why I didn’t realize before that `CallSid` was a bad idea. Thanks!